# safari - jquery - ajax 500 internal server error

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have created an jquery ajax call and it is working fine in Chrome, firefox and IE.

Where as in Safari, it is giving 500 internal server error in the response. I though it could be due to an exception from Server. But when i tried debugging, i found that it is not hitting the server at all.

The wierd thing in this is, the ajax-call works for every alternate calls. Call-1 fails and then call 2 succeeds.[image]   [image]

Am attaching the screen shot of the request and response(both success and error). Please help me to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Raghav

```
var coId = globalObject.GetCompanyIdFromUrl();
if ($("#headerCompanyMenu").length > 0 && coId != "") {
    var strData = "{\"coId\":\"" + coId + "\"}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        url: globalObject.rootPath + "search/webmethod.aspx/GetCoHeaderData",
        data: strData,
        async: true,
        success: function (d) {
            var coHeaderData = JSON.parse(d);
            $("#lblCoNm").html(coHeaderData.lblCoNm);
            $("#lbl_prim_im").html(coHeaderData.lbl_prim_im);
            $("#lbl_prim_md").html(coHeaderData.lbl_prim_md);
            $("#lbl_prd_own").html(coHeaderData.lbl_prd_own);
            $("#lbl_geo_own").html(coHeaderData.lbl_geo_own);
            $("#lbl_org_inv").html(coHeaderData.lbl_org_inv);
            $("#lbl_out_inv").html(coHeaderData.lbl_out_inv);
            $("#lbl_cur_val").html(coHeaderData.lbl_cur_val);
            $("#lbl_nbv").html(coHeaderData.lbl_nbv);
            $("#lbl_fv").html(coHeaderData.lbl_fv);
            $("#lblProc").html(coHeaderData.lblProc);
            $("#lblFinGrd").html(coHeaderData.lblFinGrd);

            if (coHeaderData.addNewDeal == "true")
                $("#lnkAddNewDeal").show();
            if (coHeaderData.coDeals.length > 0) {
                BindData("coDealsTmpl", coHeaderData.coDeals);
                $("#coDeals").show();
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            //alert("Company search error");

        }

    });
```

Am running the safari from Win7. 
The actual Mac's safari loads it perfectly fine. No errors for ajax call.

The server is windows 2008, running iis 7. No loadbalancing servers. Each time the ajax-call is hitting the same server same method, with same input-data and expects the same output data.

Comment: Paste the ajax call code; maybe there's something relevant there. Anything funky on the server that we should know about? Is that localhost box? Load balanced (multiple servers at single internal hostname, although your hostname doesn't look like a typical naming scheme for that)? Is the data you're retrieving being assembled based on something that you're overlooking, that might coincidentally be related to odds and evens? I can't think of anything else, but more info would be good.

Comment: if the data is gonna be the problem, then the breakpoint on the server should be hit, right.. Its not hitting the breakpoint @ the server during the error.

Comment: Can you see in the windows log - event viewer the error ? In you case I will try to remove the \" and place just ' for test. Maybe safari send some parametres that iis recognize them on url as dangerous, and the only think here is this slash - if safari not handle it the same way.

Comment: Yeah.. actually i had ' previously and faced the same issue. Then changed to " and facing the same issue. The slash cannot be a problem, coz it goes properly in the Request-header(image1)
Nothing comes up in event viewer. When i tried to do FailedRequestTracing, it is logged as a failed request. But i cannot figure out what is wrong from the big xml. Also i cannot attach it here in the thread.

Comment: Try using Fiddler to look at the network traffic. Might give you a clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the reason the call is failing is because of a bug in Safari when working with Windows Authentication under IIS. Go to the Authentication settings of your website. Right click on Windows Authentication, choose providers and remove Negotiate, leaving NTLM which works fine. I haven't tested Kerberos.

This issue only appears in certain builds of safari.

Answer (score 3):

**First:** I would check to make sure that $("#headerCompanyMenu").length > 0 && coId != "" evaluates to true when you think it should be.

**Second:** I would make sure that you have a '/' at the end of `globalObject.rootPath` when you are using Safari.

**Third:** I would change up your ajax post to look like this:

```
var coId = globalObject.GetCompanyIdFromUrl();
if ($("#headerCompanyMenu").length > 0 && coId != "") {
    var strData = {'coId' : coId};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        url: globalObject.rootPath + "search/webmethod.aspx/GetCoHeaderData/",
        data: strData,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (d) {
            var coHeaderData = JSON.parse(d);
            $("#lblCoNm").html(coHeaderData.lblCoNm);
            $("#lbl_prim_im").html(coHeaderData.lbl_prim_im);
            $("#lbl_prim_md").html(coHeaderData.lbl_prim_md);
            $("#lbl_prd_own").html(coHeaderData.lbl_prd_own);
            $("#lbl_geo_own").html(coHeaderData.lbl_geo_own);
            $("#lbl_org_inv").html(coHeaderData.lbl_org_inv);
            $("#lbl_out_inv").html(coHeaderData.lbl_out_inv);
            $("#lbl_cur_val").html(coHeaderData.lbl_cur_val);
            $("#lbl_nbv").html(coHeaderData.lbl_nbv);
            $("#lbl_fv").html(coHeaderData.lbl_fv);
            $("#lblProc").html(coHeaderData.lblProc);
            $("#lblFinGrd").html(coHeaderData.lblFinGrd);

            if (coHeaderData.addNewDeal == "true")
                $("#lnkAddNewDeal").show();
            if (coHeaderData.coDeals.length > 0) {
                BindData("coDealsTmpl", coHeaderData.coDeals);
                $("#coDeals").show();
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            //alert("Company search error");

        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But unfortunately nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to CCCason's comments, I would explicitly tell the ajax call that it's datatype is json by adding:

```
dataType: "json"
```

Maybe safari is guessing the wrong data type?

Comment: Added that to the blob of ajax in my answer. Good idea.