# Safari giving Undefined index error on AJAX form submit in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, post, safari

I am developing a unique cart plugin on WordPress. I am having weird `Undefined index` error only on Safari. I don't understand why it is only on safari while working fine on other browsers.

Please watch this video, there I have explained in detail.

### Video

https://youtu.be/j7wxcUYw-hU

Jump directly on the issue point

https://youtu.be/j7wxcUYw-hU?t=165

## Error

```
[08-May-2020 07:01:38 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: c_name in /Users/usrename/Sites/wpdev/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/public/plugin-name-cart-add-process-ajax.php on line 91
[08-May-2020 07:01:38 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: c_email in /Users/usrename/Sites/wpdev/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/public/plugin-name-cart-add-process-ajax.php on line 91
[08-May-2020 07:01:38 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: c_qty in /Users/usrename/Sites/wpdev/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/public/plugin-name-cart-add-process-ajax.php on line 91
```

## Code on line 91

```
// setup customers
$customers = gs_validate_customers_on_add($_POST[ 'c_name' ], $_POST[ 'c_email' ], $_POST[ 'c_qty' ], $_POST[ 'qty' ]);
```

The function `gs_validate_customers_on_add` is combining all these three fields into one associative array after validating inputs. as below

```
[
    [0] => [
        'name'  =>  'John Doe',
        'email' =>  'johndoe@email.com',
        'qty'   =>  2
    ],
    ...
]
```

## AJAX

```
$(function () {

    let response_alert = $('#response');
    response_alert.hide();

    $('form.addtocartform').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let formData = $(this).serialize();

        let names = [];
        let emails = [];

        $('input[name="name"]').each(function () {
            names.push(this.value);
        });

        $('input[name="email"]').each(function () {
            emails.push(this.value);
        });

        console.log(names);

        $.ajax({

            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_vars.ajax_url,
            data: formData + "&action=gs_add_to_cart&nonce=" + ajax_vars.nonce,
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log(this.data);
                console.log('Sending...');
            },
            success: function (response) {

                if (response.success === true) {

                    console.log(response);

                    let message = response.data.message;
                    let gifts = response.data.gifts;
                    let next_gift = response.data.next_gift;

                    // display next gift item
                    if (response.data.hasOwnProperty('next_gift')) {
                        response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('info', next_gift));
                    }

                    // display gift items
                    if (response.data.hasOwnProperty('gifts')) {
                        response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('gift', gifts));
                    }

                    // display success message
                    response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('success', message));

                    // $('#product_option').val(null);
                    $('#qty').val(1);
                    $('#product_option, .customer-name, .customer-email').val(null);
                }

                if (response.success === false) {
                    response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('error', response.data));
                }
                gs_alert_stats();

            },
            error: function (response) {

                let error_message = (response.data === undefined) ? 'Something went wrong!' : response.data;
                response_alert.fadeIn().prepend(alerts('error', error_message));
                gs_alert_stats();
            },
            complete: function () {
            }

        });

        return false;
    });

    // control dynamically created error with JS - close/hide
    function gs_alert_stats() {
        let gs_alert = $('.gs-message');
        $('.gs-close').on('click', function () {
            alerts('Clicked');
            $(this).parent(gs_alert).fadeOut();
        });
    }

});
```

## Callback Function

```
function gs_add_p_to_cart_ajax()
{
    // Check if user is logged in
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in()) {
        // throw error if user is not logged in
        wp_send_json_error(__('Please login to order', 'group-shop'));

        // we use this manually as want to print error
        wp_die();
    }

    // check and validate nonce
    if ( ! check_ajax_referer('gs_nonce', 'nonce', FALSE)) {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Do not be nasty with validation', 'group-shop'));

        // we use this manually as want to print error
        wp_die();
    }

    // prepare for data validation
    $group_id       = absint($_POST[ 'group_id' ]);
    $product        = absint($_POST[ 'product' ]);
    $qty            = absint($_POST[ 'qty' ]);
    $customers      = NULL;
    $product_option = NULL;


    if ( ! gs_group_is_active($group_id)) {

        // throw error if group is closed
        wp_send_json_error(__('Last purchase date is crossed', 'group-shop'));

    }

    // check group id
    if ( ! $group_id) {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Group is not defined', 'group-shop'));
    }

    // check product id
    if ( ! $product) {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Product is not defined', 'group-shop'));
    }

    // setup customers
    $customers = gs_validate_customers_on_add($_POST[ 'c_name' ], $_POST[ 'c_email' ], $_POST[ 'c_qty' ], $_POST[ 'qty' ]);

    // check option value
    if (isset($_POST[ 'product_option' ]) && $_POST[ 'product_option' ] === '') {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('Please select option', 'group-shop'));

    } else {

        $product_option = (isset($_POST[ 'product_option' ])) ? absint($_POST[ 'product_option' ]) : NULL;

    }

    if ($qty <= 0) {

        // throw error if validation fails
        wp_send_json_error(__('At lest one quantity is required', 'group-shop'));

    }

    // insert record
    $cart    = new Group_Shop_Cart();
    $cart_id = $cart->add_p_to_cart($group_id, $product, $qty, $customers, $product_option);

    // if record inserted
    if ($cart_id) {

        $disc = new Group_Shop_Discount();
        $disc->set_gift_response_data($group_id, get_current_user_id(), 'Product is added to cart');

        $data = [
            'message' => __('Product is added to cart', 'group-shop'),
            'gift'    => $disc->get_gift_data($group_id, get_current_user_id()),
        ];

        // show success message once record inserted
        wp_send_json_success($disc->gift_response_data);

    } else {

        // throw error if fails to insert record
        wp_send_json_error(__('Something went wrong', 'group-shop'));

    }

    // stop further execution once all process done
    wp_die();
}

// hook the function
add_action('wp_ajax_gs_add_to_cart', 'gs_add_p_to_cart_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_gs_add_to_cart', 'gs_add_p_to_cart_ajax');
```

## Header

```
Summary
URL: http://wpdev.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Source: Network
Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Initiator: 
jquery.js:4:26433


Request
POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: wpdev.org
Origin: http://wpdev.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://wpdev.org/products/pizza/?group_id=298
Content-Length: 86
Cookie: wordpress_8ce0964f9d22....45p5
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Response
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://wpdev.org
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Date: Fri, 08 May 2020 09:18:49 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Length: 178
Connection: close
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.2
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) PHP/7.4.2
X-Robots-Tag: noindex

Request Data
MIME Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
action: gs_add_to_cart
nonce: 6d13df5fc3
group_id: 298
product: 297
qty: 1
product_option: 1
```

Looking to the *Request Data* in header response, I found that the `c_name`, `c_email`, and `c_qty` is missing. I have not idea why it is not getting submitted since it is under the same form.

Comment: Have you checked for an error in the Safari console, or looked at the request being submitted on the network tab? It looks like the data is not being POSTed.

Comment: @Nick thanks for giving me a thought. In console getting the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` for `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` But why only for safari not for other browsers?

Additionally, on the network tab also stuck on `admin-ajax.php` Says failed to load

Comment: There must be something else going on which is making Safari not post the data. What about the network tab, can you see the post traffic on there? even with a `failed to load` error you should be able to see the details of the request

Comment: @Nick here is what I am getting on the network tab https://i.imgur.com/Hj6hcp2.png It stuck on the same place `admin-ajax.php`

Comment: @Nick can you please help me to see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10328616/1053190 if it is relating to my issue?

Comment: In that question they show all the request headers, payload etc. Can you get that info for yours?

Comment: @Nick I am sorry but unable to do so. But let me add my ajax code. Just for reference.

Comment: @Nick I have updated my question with `ajax` and `callback` function code. Hope that may helps.

Comment: @Nick I have added header response that may helps?

Comment: It shows the data isn't being submitted so perhaps there's an issue in the form html not being perfectly correct? Safari can be a real pain about that

Comment: But it is the same form for other browsers too. So I am in real trouble to find the bug and responsible source. :S

Comment: Can you post it to the question? As I mentioned, Safari is a lot more fussy about HTML syntax than other browsers, it may be something in there that Safari doesn't like but the others just ignore.